# Increase performance on MongoDB query

Tags: java, mongodb, optimization, mongodb-java

I have a 4GB mongodb database holding ip to geo data. The data looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d1c15d3a673a1a57f20251"), "IP_FROM" : NumberLong(1168612352), "IP_TO" : NumberLong(1168612607), "COUNTRY_CODE" : "US", "COUNTRY_NAME" : "UNITED STATES", "REGION" : "MICHIGAN", "CITY" : "LANSING", "LATITUDE" : 42.73328, "LONGITUDE" : -84.637765 }
```

I have java code that queries the database:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("IP_TO", new BasicDBObject("$gte", ipNum));

DBCursor cursor = ipCollection.find(query).limit(1);
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject next = cursor.next();
            latitude = (Double) next.get("LATITUDE");
            longitude = (Double) next.get("LONGITUDE");
            System.out.println("LATITUTDE: " +latitude+" LONGITUDE: "+ longitude);
            break;
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

When I run db.currentOp I get:

```
"query" : {
            "IP_TO" : {
                "$gte" : NumberLong(1625798904)
            }
        }
```

Which is way too long. Is there any way to speed up this query?

Comment: Just wondering: Is MongoDB part of the solution or part of the problem? Seriously, geo ip lookups are pretty simple. It's easy to make tens of millions of lookups per second with just a few lines of code without any 3rd party software.

Comment: @nosid I would prefer to use the mongodb database. I already have a working solution that involves using GET requests to freegeoip. What were you thinking? Is it well-maintained?

Comment: I use MaxMind's [GeoLite City](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) database. I download and transform the files, and do the lookups from my Python apps. As I said, it's fast enough to make tens of millions of ip lookups per second with about 30 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

index on IP_TO and IP_FROM can help